# How would I get total balance after each transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Hei guys. I am desperately seeking help.
[Please take a look at this image first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNYBm.png)
Thanks. Now

Please look at the table below. The rightmost column REMAINING BALANCE is holding the SUM of credit_amount - debit_amount. But when I add a new amount of credit it changes in the entire column. For example, the REMAINING BALANCE column has 102500.0. If I add 500 of credit is supposed to give me 102500 + 500 = 103000 only in that specific row. 102500 will stay same in the previous row. But my problem is, it changes in the entire column.

And I have used this repository to sum the total amount of credit and subtract total amount of debit.

```
// Find remaining balance
@Query("SELECT SUM(b.credit_amount - b.debit_amount) FROM Mosque b")
double remainingBalance();
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You need a subquery to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that you need to specify a criteria in your query, otherwise, the SQL query (or JPQL in your case) will be applied to the entire table...

I'd do something like:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(b.credit_amount - b.debit_amount) FROM Mosque b where b.id =?")
double remainingBalance(int id);
```

Otherwise, without criteria, for each Domain Object you have, you will query the entire table. Hence, you will always get the same result. If you run this query in your Database, you will see that you will have only one result, as SUM is "summing" all your rows together.